# Using Xamarin and Azure B2C with MSAL

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get a sample application to run using Xamarin and Azure B2C.  I have everything set up and working but I am not getting a access_token back to use when connecting to the API.  The sample I am following is:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/

All the claims are coming back just fine except the access token is null.

What would cause the access token to be null?

This is the code, I am using to get the access token:

````
public static string[] Scopes = { "https://{tenant Name}.onmicrosoft.com/api://{guid from API Permissions}/Files.Read" }
AuthenticationResult authResult = await
PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(B2CConstants.Scopes)
                .WithAccount(GetAccountByPolicy(accounts, B2CConstants.PolicySignUpSignIn))
                .WithParentActivityOrWindow(ParentActivityOrWindow)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            var token = authResult.AccessToken;
```
````

Comment: What's in `B2CConstants.Scopes`?

Comment: Are you sure that `var token = authResult.AccessToken;` is being called after the authResult actually gets populated?

Comment: @juunas I added the scope definition.

Comment: @Saamer, The other results in authResult are populated.

Comment: @ChrisSmathers if you're not getting an AT back, it's probably because the scope is not correct. do you have everything registered correctly in the portal? And you've updated all the values in B2CConstants.cs to reflect the values you have registered?